# How can i fix the 'myLogin' does not exist in the current content?

Tags: c#

I have been doing a exercise from my c# course and I don't get it to work, here is the actual assignment:

> Create a user control named "LoginPasswordUserControl". The "LoginPasswordUserControl" contains a label (loginLabel) that displays string "Login: ", a textbox (loginTextBox) where the user inputs a login name, a label (passwordLabel) that displays the string "Password:", and finally, a Textbox (passwordTextBox) where a user inputs a password (do not forget to setproperty Passwordchar to "*" in the TextBox's Properties window).

> LoginPasswordUserControl must provide Public read-only properties
> Login and Password that allow an application to retrieve the user input from loginTextBox and passwordTextBox.

Here is the LoginPasswordUserControl code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LoginApp
{
    public partial class LoginPasswordUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public LoginPasswordUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Login
        {
            get
            {
                return loginTextBox.Text;
            }
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return passwordTextBox.Text;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

And here is the code for the application which is where I'm getting the error message:

> The name 'myLogin' does not exist in the current content

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UserControlTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OK_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (myLogin.Login != "" && myLogin.Password != "")

        {

            displayLabel.Text = "The information entered is:";

            loginLabel.Text =
            "Login: " + myLogin.Login;

            passwordLabel.Text =
            "Password: " + myLogin.Password;

        } 
        else

            displayLabel.Text = "Enter information above";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to occur since i have to have the button click in the forms app and the textboxes are imported through the toolbox, any suggestions?

this is what my book says is the answer so i'm a bit confused, thanks for helping out!

Comment: Where is myLogin declared/initialized? I would assume it's done in a designer file outside of Form1's... but I can't say with 100% certainty.

Comment: myLogin is referencing the UserControl which has been dragged onto the form in the designer surface, see my answer below.

Comment: Did you actually rename the user control that you added to be named myLogin on the designer where you dragged it?  It's in the properties for the user control specifically.  And are you sure you dragged the control onto Form1?  Does it show visually?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First, comment out the myLogin.Login code (where your code has the red squigglies).

Next, build (compile) the project successfully.  The LoginPasswordUserControl will then be added to your Toolbox.

[image]

Next, drag the LoginPasswordUserControl to your Form's design surface from the Toolbox.  It will be created as loginPasswordUserControl1.

You can change the name of your newly instantiated UserControl by right-clicking on it in the designer, select properties, and change the name.

[image]

[image]

That worked for me.

Comment: But this class is not static. There should be an instance created in designer I assume since this is Windows Forms application.

Comment: I'm assuming he has an instance of the user control on the form

Comment: if you have downvoted my answer, please reconsider with my updated answer.

Comment: I reconsidered.  And I still don't think it's an answer.

Comment: I think it's a great answer, but I'm waiting to see yours because I want to learn from you how you would answer the question differently.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer.  Feel free to upvote it as I feel it was wrongly downvoted.

Comment: Undownvoted. But honestly, probably would have been better to delete and re-answer. I just happened to check back, but I'd doubt most downvoters will as well. And it's basically an entirely different answer from the old one.

Comment: It really only expands on my original answer, and thank you for undownvoting!